Is it correct to say "squeeze the tube using the flat side of the toothbrush"?

When my tube is almost out of toothpaste, I often apply the flat side of the toothbrush head onto the tube and run it all the way to the neck of the tube to get some toothpaste out.
I just want to efficiently squeeze the toothpaste out of the tube, ensuring that none is wasted and allowing for easy dispensing. The action is to run the toothpaste tube from the bottom up, pushing the toothpaste towards the opening for convenient and economical use.
Is it correct to say "squeeze the tube using the flat side of the toothbrush" or "squeeze the tube on the flat side of the toothbrush"?

You could say (and do) that; I roll mine up.

When done with squeezing, I cut off the top end of the tube and scrape the paste out with my brush

The first is fine. The second example doesn't make sense.

Show..... don't tell

In the US, many locksmith shops have little "wringer" rolls (a miniature version of what used to be found on an old-fashioned clothes washing machine) and for a modest fee they will put your toothpaste tube "through the wringer". You do have to bring your own carrying vessel. Some of the high-end department stores sell little gold "toothpaste boxes" to capture the last dribs and drabs of your Colgate or Crest or Sensodyne or whatever.

@TimR - In the UK, I'm sure elsewhere (because they are surely made in China) in 'budget stores' ('pound shops' we call them, in the US they are 'dollar stores', I think?) you can buy little plastic 'toothpaste squeezers' like this one

Your first sentence is correct: squeeze the tube using the flat side of the toothbrush. Here are a few other ways that you could say this:

Squeeze the tube with the flat side of the toothbrush.
Squish the tube using the flat side of the toothbrush.

